# Application is getting killed after enable/disable permissions from settings on Android M nexus 6

Tags: permissions, application-restart, android-6.0-marshmallow

Application is restarting after enable/disble the permissions from Settings->apps->my app->Permissions. Adb can see  Permission related app op changed... ,

```
08-31 14:30:29.480 I/ActivityManager( 8206): Displayed com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.ManagePermissionsActivity: +392ms

08-31 14:30:29.496 D/OpenGLRenderer(15990): endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9a60bd80 (ListView) with handle 0x97d4c1f0

08-31 14:30:30.477 D/audio_hw_primary( 7972): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2

08-31 14:30:30.522 D/AudioFlinger( 7972): mixer(0xb3ec0000) throttle end: throttle time(5)

08-31 14:30:31.298 I/ActivityManager( 8206): Killing 28808:com.sample.ui/u0a109 (adj 2): Permission related app op changed
```

Comment: It's the expected behavior

Answer (score 17):

If you have background process or services running in the background , then if user revokes permission from settings , the process gets restarted. This shouldn't affect your activity unless your activity context is tied to your service.The speaker in Google IO 2015-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17qe9vZ8RM does tell about process restart ,etc....

Comment: Is this written in the documentation anywhere? i can't seem to find anything that explicitly says this should happen

Comment: Same, I can't find anything on this besides what was said by the speaker at Google IO 2015.

Comment: 11:03 of the video, the speaker talk about this.

Comment: There still does not seem to be a written official documentation.

Comment: This is still valid for current android versions.

Comment: @LucianoBrum were you able to figure this out?