# Android App is getting recreated when changing the Permission explicitly from setting page

Tags: android, android-permissions

1)Create an app which ask for camera permission.
2)User grant the permission
3)Now  minimize the app 
4)Go to Setting -> Apps --> Your Application-->revoke the camera permission
5)Now activity getting created ,how to stop recreating .

I found this one but how i can achieve this
[Application is getting killed after enable/disable permissions from settings on Android M nexus 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307786/application-is-getting-killed-after-enable-disable-permissions-from-settings-on)

Comment: I also noticed fragment stack is also reversed. for example if i am on home-> location fragment. go to setting revoke setting. open app. current fragment will be home. press back button location fragment will appear.

Comment: any answer? I am also stuck with this scenario now